# Event-Driven Client/Server Design with C++

Tags: c++, client, event-driven

I am designing a game server with scripting capabilities. The general design goes like this:

```
Client connects to Server,
Server initializes Client,
Server sends Client to EventManager (separate thread, uses libevent),
EventManager receives receive Event from Client socket,
Client manages what it received via callbacks.
```

Now the last part is what's the most tricky for me now.

Currently my design allows me for a class which inherits `Client` to create callbacks to specific received events. These callbacks are managed in a list and the received buffer goes through a parsing process each time something is received. If the buffer is valid, the callback is called where it is act upon what is in the buffer. One thing to note is that the callbacks can go down to the scripting engine, at which point nothing is sure what can happen.

Each time a callback finishes, the current receive buffer has to be reset etc. Callbacks currently have no capability of returning a value, because as stated before, anything can happen.

What happens is that when somewhere in the callback something says this->disconnect(), I want to immediately disconnect the `Client`, remove it from the `EventManager`, and lastly remove it from the `Server`, where it also should get finally destructed and free memory. However, I still have some Code running after the callback finishes in the Client, thus I can't free memory.

What should I change in the design? Should I have some timed event in the `Server` which checks which `Client`s are free to destroy? Would that create additional overhead I don't need? Would it still be okay after the callback finishes to run minimal code on the stack (`return -1;`) or not?

I have no idea what to do, but I am open for complete design revamps.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a reference counted pointer like `boost::shared_ptr<>` to simplify memory management. If the manager's client list uses `shared_ptr`s and the code that calls the callbacks creates a local copy of the `shared_ptr` the callback is called on, the object will stay alive until it is removed from the manager *and* the callback function is complete:

```
class EventManager {
  std::vector< boost::shared_ptr<Client> > clients;

  void handle_event(Event &event) {
    // local |handler| pointer keeps object alive until end of function, even
    // if it removes itselfe from |clients|
    boost::shared_ptr<Client> handler = ...;
    handler->process(event);
  }
};

class Client {
  void process(Event &event) {
    manager->disconnect(this);
    // the caller still holds a reference, so the object lives on
  }
}
```

The `Client` object will automatically be deleted once the last `shared_ptr` to it goes out of scope, but not before. So creating a local copy of the `shared_ptr` before a function call makes sure the object is not deleted unexpectedly.

Comment: This will require the least changes from the current system, so I opt for this. I will still consider the suggestions of the others. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You should consider having an object like "Session" which will track particular message flow from start to finish (from 1 client). 
This object should also take care of current state: primarily the buffers and processing. 
Each event which triggers a callback MUST update the state of corresponding session.
Libevent is capable of providing you with any result of scheduled event: success, failure, timeout. Each of this types should be reflected with your logic.
In general, when working with events, consider your processing logic to be an automaton with a state.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reactor_pattern may be a good resource for your task.

Answer (score 0):

Let the Client::disconnect() function send an event to the EventManager (or Server) class. This means that you need some sort of event handling in EventManager (or Server), an event loop for instance.

My general idea is that Client::disconnect() does not disconnect the Client immediately, but only after the callback finished executing. Instead, it just posts an event to the EventManager (or Server) class.

One could argue that the Client::disconnect() method is on the wrong class. Maybe it should be Server::disconnect( Client *c ). That would be more in-line with the idea that the Server 'owns' the Client and it's the Server which disconnects Clients (and then updates some internal bookkeeping).